# how to upgrade ios sdk for google glass app development

Tags: ios, xcode, google-glass

I am new bie to xcode.I want to create google glass app in ios.I googled many sites.But didn't find proper information regarding this and even want to know how to upgrade google glass API in xcode. please give any links and suggestions to develop sample google glass app in xcode.Thanks for your suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be using the Mirror API, which is a REST based web API. Although the [Google Objective C library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/) supports the Mirror API, there is not a lot of documentation on its use. You can see the [Mirror API documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/index) for generic guidance which you will need to apply to the specific ObjC implementation.

**Update**: While you don't need to download or use this library, if you don't, you'll need to use HTTPS calls to Google's servers instead. You should read the documentation about the Mirror API at https://developers.google.com/glass/

Comment: thanks for your reply.do i need to download this mirror api for xcode?.or any other configuration for google glass app development.can you give me any code snippet for hello world example.

Comment: I don't have a code snippet (I don't use ObjC), but answer updated with some more information and links.